# Redirect Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, mobile

So I'm using jquerymobile for an app I'm creating.  I have a link that if all the validation passes I'd like to go through, but if something fails I'd like to redirect.

In the jquery something like this.  Since it is jquerymobile the link will be a new div on the same index.html page - if that helps.

```
$(#link).click(function(){  
  if(validation_fails) link_elsewhere;  
  else return true;
}
```

Comment: this truely is just javascript, nothing really going on with jquery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the window.location to redirect a browser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 13):

You can use JavaScript's **native** [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

```
$('#link').click(function(){  

    if(validation_fails) {
        window.location="http://this.site.com/";
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hash the div id to the window.location to display the div.
Something like:

```
$(#link).click(function(){  
  if(validation_fails) window.location += "#<YOUR_DIV_ID>" ;  
  else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(#link).click(function(){  
  if(validation_fails){
    var loc = window.location;
    window.location = loc.protocol+"//"+loc.hostname+loc.pathname+"#somedivid";
  } else return true;
}
```

You need the extra code beyond @Cybermate's answer because otherwise you'll keep appending the hash each time it fails, e.g. "http://foo.com/bar#whee", then ""http://foo.com/bar#whee#whee", etc.

**Edit**: 
If the port might be used, you can conditionally include it:

```
window.location = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname +
                  (loc.port && ":"+loc.port) + 
                  loc.pathname + "#somedivid";
```

Comment: loc.port can be used when port number needed